# Struggling to design an appropriate core data layout based on my class diagram due to its different take on relationships and inheritence

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data

I am new to swift and I am currently having trouble figuring out how best to go about designing my core data entity map.

My class diagram defines: 
1) a student object
2) subject objects
3) event objects (which is a parent class to 3 types of events: Study session, assignment and test, each with various unique attributes)

The idea is that the student is linked to the subjects that they take, and when they create an event (be it a test, or a study session), the event needs to be linked to its relevant subject.

I've read quite a bit about inheritance in core data but a lot of them contradict each other so I am hoping someone can give me an answer based on my specific (although not complex) needs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless you really understand and need inheritance in Core Data avoid it. What happens is the entire inheritance tree is merges in one wide table table. Where you may be thinking of inheritance in a DB think parent/clild(ren) relationships. Basically one way to think of the Core Data entity design is as a relational database close to a normalized form.

Comment: In general take a day (at least) and study basic database design.

Comment: I do understand that I should avoid it, and I have read about the issue of it being merged in one table. I do understand database design, but the rules apply differently here it seems. This is where I get confused. Does avoiding this in the core data entity layout mean I have to approach setting up the class layer differently, and if so how? My class diagram represents and EVENT class as the parent with common attributes, and the children class inheriting from it. Should I just replicate all common attributes in each class and exclude any sort of subclassing at all?

Comment: I think the crucial question is how you wish to handle the relationships from the Subject entity.  If you do not use parent/child entities for Event, StudySession, etc, then the Subject entity will need to have three separate relationships.  That will be a pain if you need to amalgamate all the Events into a single collection eg. for table views.

Comment: @pbasdf thanks for the input :) This would be the case if I were to access the students schedule, where I would want to see all upcomming study sessions, tests and assignment deadlines. This being the case, what would you suggest?

Comment: @Glenncito Personally, I think that is enough justification for using parent/child entities.  But I would invest some time to generate test data to confirm whether the performance hit is tolerable.

Answer (score 1):

If you break it in parts you have:

**Student to Subject**: What is a many-to-many relationship as a student can subscribe to many subjects and a subject can be subscribe for many students

**Subject to Event:**
This can be in two ways:

1. Many-to-many:

   where a Subject can have many events related to it and an event can be related to many subjects
2. Many-to-one:

   Where a Subject can have many events to it but each event belong to just one class

In this scenario Students don't get linked to Events directly as it is depending in with subjects the student is taking.

You can set to-many in the xcode as show bellow:

[image]

To set many-to-many you have to set this option in both tables.

I am not sure if this was what you are looking for, but I hope it helps you.

Comment: @zaph do you think would be more efficient to have an "in between" table holding the relationship? I use a similar structure before, many-to-many-to-one. I didn't see any problems (maybe because wasn't a very big database)

Comment: Sorry, in Core Data many-to-many are fine. I was thinking more of general database design. Core Data will automatically create the join table(s) behind the scenes. If you look at the database scheme with an app like Base you will see these join tables.

Comment: Hi @Icaro, thank you for your answer, it does answer some of my question. What I was am most confused about however is how to setup the event table, and how to represent subclassing event (Test, assignment or worksession), without using inheritance since the online community warns against doing that. 

And on that note, once I have set up the entitys appropriately, how does that affect setting up my event class structure which I intend to set up  according to my class diagram (which shows my event parent class and then its children classes which inherits the event class's attributes).